# How to Filter Array Elements for Arrays Two Levels Deep?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

In my collection I have an array, inside which there are objects, inside which there are arrays. My data looks like this:

```
{
  'settings': {
    'labourContributions': [
      {
        'show': True,
        'Accrual': True,
        '_id': ObjectId('abc'),
        'name': 'Holidays',
        'amount': 10,
        'target': [
          {
            'date': 2021-05-17T23: 00: 00.000+00: 00,
            'percent': 4.0
          },
          {
            'date': 2021-05-19T23: 00: 00.000+00: 00,
            'percent': 10.0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'show': True,
        'Accrual': True,
        '_id': ObjectId('abd'),
        'name': 'Taxes',
        'amount': 10,
        'target': [
          {
            'date': 2021-04-01T23: 00: 00.000+00: 00,
            'percent': 8.0
          },
          {
            'date': 2021-05-27T23: 00: 00.000+00: 00,
            'percent': 10.0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My aim is to return all elements of `labourContributions` according to some match, but within `labourContributions.target` I only want one element, according to some other match (let's say `percent` > 5).

Attempting this using an aggregation pipeline I can only get so far:

```
c = collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "settings.labourContributions": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Accrual": True
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "settings.labourContributions.$.target": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$settings.labourContributions.$.target",
          "as": "contributions",
          "cond": {
            "$gt": [
              "$$contributions.percent",
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I don't think the `$project` stage can support `$` slices of arrays. How can I query based on my deeper array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think the `$project` stage can support `$` slices of arrays. How can I query based on my deeper array?

You can only use `$` position in update queries,

- `$match` your both condition using nested `$elemMatch`
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `labourContributions` and filter main documents by `Accrual` condition
- `$map` to iterate loop of a above filtered documents
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `target` array and filter documents by `percent`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of map and filtered `target` array

```
c = collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "settings.labourContributions": {
        $elemMatch: {
          Accrual: true,
          target: {
            $elemMatch: {
              percent: { $gt: 5 }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "settings.labourContributions": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$settings.labourContributions",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.Accrual", true] }
            }
          },
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                target: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$this.target",
                    cond: { $gt: ["$$this.percent", 5] }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VEECGT5iMvB)